# cambiar inner join por subconsulta

Tags: mysql, sql

es posible cambiar esta consulta con inner join por una subconsulta?

```
select usuarios.nombre from usuarios inner join ventas on usuarios.id=ventas.idUsuario;
```

Comment: ¿Por qué necesitas dicho cambio?

Comment: Y si se puede, para eso existe algo llamado: `WHERE EXISTS`

Comment: Así como está planteada la pregunta, la respuesta es "si se puede".

Answer (score 1):

Si, se se puede hacer uso de sub-consultas para obtener el mismo resultado:

```
SELECT usuarios.nombre 
FROM usuarios 
WHERE usuarios.id IN (SELECT ventas.idUsuario FROM ventas);
```

Aunque es oportuno decir que a pesar de que factores como el tamaño de la tabla o el uso de indices puede repercutir en los tiempos de respuesta que demora la ejecución de la consulta, en la mayoría de los casos el uso apropiado del INNER será mas optimo que el uso de las sub-consultas.

Claro esta, que si se trata de tablas con pocos registros, los costos de la ejecución de la consulta entre uno u otro es imperceptible.

Comment: no da el mismo resultado. Como puedes ver en esta captura: https://postimg.cc/Z01T6xSw el usuario con id=2 tiene dos compras y con tu subonsulta solo me muestra un resultado: https://postimg.cc/jCjXyyXn, yo quiero que me aparezcan los dos resultados: https://postimg.cc/RWCV0V9m